# CSS List styling - marker bullet not shown even with appropriate list-style-type

Tags: css, html-lists, display, inspection

I have explicitly styled my `ul` elements to have `list-style-type: disc`. The `li` elements within an `ul` automatically inherit this styling. In other words, there should be bullet (which is what `disc` stands for) before each `li` element.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: disc; /* Does not work */
}
li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Foo</li>
  <li>Bar</li>
  <li>Baz</li>
</ul>
```

Firefox Inspector devtool correctly recognizes that all `li` elements in the list have the (inherited) value 'disc' for the property `list-style-type`.

However, as you can also see if you run the snippet, the disc (that is, the bullet) is NOT actually displayed in the browser representation. Instead, the list is displayed as if `list-style-type` was defined as `none` (i.e. no bullet or any symbol is seen in front of the `li` elements).

I'm wondering how this is possible at all: It seems that the browser display (no bullet) stands in direct contradiction to the declaration `list-style-type: disc` as correctly shown in the Inspector tool.

Anyone have an explanation for the apparent contradiction between what the Inspector tool (correctly) says and the actual browser representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because it has

```css
display: block;
```

If you want a marker, the proper display should be

```css
display: list-item;
```

Note this should be the default value for `li` elements. The [Default style sheet for HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) contains

```css
li { display: list-item }
```

> [**2.3. Generating Marker Boxes: the `list-item` keyword**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#list-items)
>
> The [`list-item`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#valdef-display-list-item) keyword causes the element to generate a
>   [`::marker`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-pseudo-4/#selectordef-marker) pseudo-element box [[CSS-PSEUDO-4]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#biblio-css-pseudo-4) with the
>   content specified by its [`list-style`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-lists/#propdef-list-style) properties ([CSS 2.1§12.5
>   Lists](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#lists)) [[CSS2]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#biblio-css2) together with a principal box of the
>   specified type for its own contents.

Otherwise, [`list-style-*`](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#list-style) properties don't apply:

> **Applies to**: elements with `display: list-item`

Comment: Yes, I 've tried it, and you're 100% correct! Thank you so much. I'll accept the answer after the waiting time.